# Proof regarding the minimum of a function

Tags: calculus, inequality, curves, maxima-minima

I want to show that the function

$$f(x)= \frac{2x}{1+(\frac{1}{k-x})^a} +  \frac{k-2x}{1+2\cdot(\frac{1}{k-x})^a+ (\frac{1}{k-2x})^a}$$

with

$$ x \in [0,\frac{k}{2}], a \in [0,\infty], k \in [0,1] $$

has the minimum

$$min(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
\frac{k}{1+3\cdot(\frac{1}{k})^a},\, a\leq \frac{log(3)}{log(2)}
\\ 
\frac{k}{1+(\frac{1}{k/2})^a} ,\, else
\end{cases}$$

for all permited values of the parameters $a,k$. The minima can be obtained by setting either $x=0$ or $x=\frac{k}{2}$. I checked that this is in fact the minimum by simulating the function for all permitted parameter values.

My initial idea was to use the generalized version of the Binomial theorem 
on the $1/(k-x)^a$ terms, but this only worked for $a\leq2$ because the elements of the series obtained from the theorem are not shrinking in absolute value.

Another idea was to show that every critical point of the function is never a global minimum, but I cannot find a solution for $f'(x)=0$.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

We can also prove the case when $a > \frac{11}{4}$.

We will use Fact 1 and 2 whose proof is simple and thus omitted.

**Fact 1**: If $a > \frac{11}{4}$, we have
$$\frac{2x}{1+(\frac{1}{k-x})^a} \ge \frac{k}{1 + (\frac{2}{k})^a}$$
for $\frac{k}{4} \le x \le \frac{k}{2}$.

**Fact 2**: If $a > \frac{11}{4}$, we have
$$\frac{k^2}{k + 2(k-x)^{1-a} + (k-2x)^{1-a}} \ge \frac{k}{1+(\frac{2}{k})^a}$$
for $0\le x \le \frac{k}{4}$.

Now let us proceed.

If $0\le x\le \frac{k}{4}$, using the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality and Fact 2, we have
$$f(x) \ge \frac{k^2}{k + 2(k-x)^{1-a} + (k-2x)^{1-a}} \ge  \frac{k}{1+(\frac{2}{k})^a}.$$

If $\frac{k}{4} \le x \le \frac{k}{2}$, using Fact 1, we have
$$f(x) \ge \frac{2x}{1+(\frac{1}{k-x})^a} \ge \frac{k}{1 + (\frac{2}{k})^a}.$$

**Previously written**

**Partial answer**

I prove the case when $0 < a < 1$. (The case $a=1$ is easy.)

Let
\begin{align}
g(x) &= 2x \Big(1 + \Big(\frac{1}{k-x}\Big)^a\Big)
+ (k-2x)\Big(1 + 2\Big(\frac{1}{k-x}\Big)^a + \Big(\frac{1}{k-2x}\Big)^a\Big)\\
&= k + 2(k-x)^{1-a} + (k-2x)^{1-a}.
\end{align}

Using the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$f(x) \ge \frac{(2x + k-2x)^2}{g(x)} = \frac{k^2}{g(x)}.$$

If $0 < a < 1$, then $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $x\in [0, k/2]$.
We have $f(x) \ge \frac{k^2}{g(0)} = \frac{k^2}{k+ 3k^{1-a}} = f(0)$.We are done.

Comment: Very good, thank you very much! Any ideas on how to deal with $a>1$ and especially $a>log(3)/log(2)$? For $a>1$, $g(x)$ is strictly increasing with $g(x) \rightarrow \infty$ for $x \rightarrow k/2$, so one cannot use the same method and definition of $g(x)$ to prove the limits. Maybe using

\begin{align}
g(x) &:= \frac{1}{2x} \frac{1}{1 + \Big(\frac{1}{k-x}\Big)^a}
+ \frac{1}{k-2x}\frac{1}{1 + 2\Big(\frac{1}{k-x}\Big)^a + \Big(\frac{1}{k-2x}\Big)^a}
\end{align}
?

Comment: I can also prove the case when $a > \frac{11}{4}$.

Comment: Great! Thanks again. This only leaves the two cases $1\leq x \leq \frac{log(3)}{log(2)}$  and $\frac{log(3)}{log(2)} \lt x \leq \frac{11}{4}$. I hope somebody finds the solution!